# React Native CLI Xcode fails a build (simulator) after updating to XCode 15 and iOS 17

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, simulator, ios17

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EZLY.jpg) After installing XCode 15 on my MAC air m2 and iOS 17 I'm trying to build React native app with Iphone 15 Rosetta simulator but I'm getting error, it was doing fine with iOS 16.4 rosetta builds .
I tried pod install --repo-update
I tried to build with iOS 16.2 rosetta simulators but I get same error.
However it works fine if I change in FIRFirestoneSettings.mm
ABSL_CONST_INIT extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited =
Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;
to
extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited =
Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;
Reference: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/issues/830#issuecomment-1727338004
Here is code of file FIRFirestoreSettings.mm

```
/*
 * Copyright 2017 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

#import "FIRFirestoreSettings.h"

#include "Firestore/core/src/api/settings.h"
#include "Firestore/core/src/util/exception.h"
#include "Firestore/core/src/util/string_apple.h"
#include "absl/base/attributes.h"
#include "absl/memory/memory.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

namespace api = firebase::firestore::api;
using api::Settings;
using firebase::firestore::util::MakeString;
using firebase::firestore::util::ThrowInvalidArgument;

// Public constant
ABSL_CONST_INIT extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited =
    Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;

@implementation FIRFirestoreSettings

- (instancetype)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _host = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:Settings::DefaultHost];
    _sslEnabled = Settings::DefaultSslEnabled;
    _dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    _persistenceEnabled = Settings::DefaultPersistenceEnabled;
    _cacheSizeBytes = Settings::DefaultCacheSizeBytes;
  }
  return self;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
  if (self == other) {
    return YES;
  } else if (![other isKindOfClass:[FIRFirestoreSettings class]]) {
    return NO;
  }

  FIRFirestoreSettings *otherSettings = (FIRFirestoreSettings *)other;
  return [self.host isEqual:otherSettings.host] &&
         self.isSSLEnabled == otherSettings.isSSLEnabled &&
         self.dispatchQueue == otherSettings.dispatchQueue &&
         self.isPersistenceEnabled == otherSettings.isPersistenceEnabled &&
         self.cacheSizeBytes == otherSettings.cacheSizeBytes;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
  NSUInteger result = [self.host hash];
  result = 31 * result + (self.isSSLEnabled ? 1231 : 1237);
  // Ignore the dispatchQueue to avoid having to deal with sizeof(dispatch_queue_t).
  result = 31 * result + (self.isPersistenceEnabled ? 1231 : 1237);
  result = 31 * result + (NSUInteger)self.cacheSizeBytes;
  return result;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(__unused NSZone *_Nullable)zone {
  FIRFirestoreSettings *copy = [[FIRFirestoreSettings alloc] init];
  copy.host = _host;
  copy.sslEnabled = _sslEnabled;
  copy.dispatchQueue = _dispatchQueue;
  copy.persistenceEnabled = _persistenceEnabled;
  copy.cacheSizeBytes = _cacheSizeBytes;
  return copy;
}

- (void)setHost:(NSString *)host {
  if (!host) {
    ThrowInvalidArgument("Host setting may not be nil. You should generally just use the default "
                         "value (which is %s)",
                         Settings::DefaultHost);
  }
  _host = [host mutableCopy];
}

- (void)setDispatchQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)dispatchQueue {
  if (!dispatchQueue) {
    ThrowInvalidArgument(
        "Dispatch queue setting may not be nil. Create a new dispatch queue with "
        "dispatch_queue_create(\"com.example.MyQueue\", NULL) or just use the default (which is "
        "the main queue, returned from dispatch_get_main_queue())");
  }
  _dispatchQueue = dispatchQueue;
}

- (void)setCacheSizeBytes:(int64_t)cacheSizeBytes {
  if (cacheSizeBytes != kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited &&
      cacheSizeBytes < Settings::MinimumCacheSizeBytes) {
    ThrowInvalidArgument("Cache size must be set to at least %s bytes",
                         Settings::MinimumCacheSizeBytes);
  }
  _cacheSizeBytes = cacheSizeBytes;
}

- (BOOL)isUsingDefaultHost {
  NSString *defaultHost = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:Settings::DefaultHost];
  return [self.host isEqualToString:defaultHost];
}

- (Settings)internalSettings {
  Settings settings;
  settings.set_host(MakeString(_host));
  settings.set_ssl_enabled(_sslEnabled);
  settings.set_persistence_enabled(_persistenceEnabled);
  settings.set_cache_size_bytes(_cacheSizeBytes);
  return settings;
}

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess only fix at this point is to change in FIRFirestoneSettings.mm ABSL_CONST_INIT extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited = Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;
To
extern "C" const int64_t kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited = Settings::CacheSizeUnlimited;
Reference: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/issues/830#issuecomment-1727338004

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).